# Diebold-Mariano test: robust standard errors for 1-day ahead forecasts?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, forecasting, autocorrelation, neweywest, diebold-mariano-test

Diebold & Mariano suggest using Newey-West standard errors to correct for autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity in the error terms when comparing forecast accuracy.

However, if I understand correctly, they also assume dependency only for (k-1) day ahead forecast errors.

As such, am I correct in assuming that I do not need to use Newey-West standard errors when looking at 1-day ahead forecasts?

Comment: The implementation code of the test in R package "forecast" function `dm.test` is quite easy to read; there you see that the variance estimation accounts for autocorrelation up to $h-1$.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 3):

**Autocorrelation**
$h$-step-ahead forecast errors for $h>1$ are autocorrelated by construction, because the forecasts cover overlapping time periods. This holds even for "optimal" forecasts. Meanwhile, 1-step-ahead forecast errors need not be autocorrelated, at least for "optimal" forecasts.

However, they still *might* be autocorrelated for "suboptimal" forecasts. E.g. if the forecast for $t+1$ is just the actual value as of $t-k$ for some $k>0$, you effectively get the same overlap and thus autocorrelation in forecast errors as with $h$-step-ahead forecasts. Of course, this need not be a sensible forecast, but it serves as an example.

Using autocorrelation-robust standard errors for 1-step-ahead forecasts in the Diebold-Mariano test is thus a conservative, "safe" choice.

**Heteroskedasticity**
Regarding heteroskedasticity, neither [Diebold & Mariano (1995)](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.1995.10524599) nor [Diebold (2015)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236) mentions it, so probably there is nothing special about it in the context of the Diebold-Mariano test. If there is reason to believe that the forecast error distribution had a varying variance in your sample, you could use the heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors.

**References:**

- Diebold, Francis X., and Roberto S. Mariano. ["Comparing Predictive Accuracy."](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.1995.10524599) *Journal of Business & Economic Statistics* 13.3 (1995): 253-263.
- Diebold, Francis X. ["Comparing predictive accuracy, twenty years later: A personal perspective on the use and abuse of Diebold–Mariano tests."](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236) *Journal of Business & Economic Statistics* 33.1 (2015): 1-1.

Comment: Now I started wondering myself what one should do with "suboptimal" forecasts. Does the fact that the 1-step-ahead forecast errors are autocorrelated effectively reduce the sample (as with optimal $h$-step-ahead forecasts) so that we have to use autocorrelation-robust variance estimator? Or do the errors carry independent information nevertheless and regular variance estimator should be used?